# searching array with missing variables

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

This does what I need it to, I am just tring to simplify it a little more. I designed this off off various things I found on the internet. Problem is if add more messages and do not adjust the number of messages in the loop it crashes at the end, I would like to get around that. any ideas?

```
var chatMessages = [chatMessage0 = "",
chatMessage1 = " this",
chatMessage2 = " is",
chatMessage3 = " almost",
chatMessage4 = " perfect",
chatMessage5 = " for what I need",
chatMessage999 = ""];
var chatMessageCount = 5;
var chatNow = [];

chat();
function chat() {
    for (i = 0; i < chatMessageCount + 2; i++) {
        chatNow = chatMessages[i];
        if (chatNow.length > 0) {
            alert(chatNow);
        }
    }
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/OldGuyGamer/t5t93/3/)

Comment: What are you trying to do with that array assignment? Array elements don't have names. It seems like you're confusing arrays with objects.

Comment: Are you just looking for `chatMessages.length`?

Comment: i have only been doing this for a week, and i am teaching my self, sorry for the confusion. got the info from here. http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp

Comment: yes, but problem is if i set it for like 999 scans, it crashes when it can not find 999,

Comment: is there a way to look for if it exists, - man please forgive me, I dont know the lingo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the `chatMessageCount` variable. Just use `chatMessages.length`.

```
var chatMessages = [
    "",
    " this",
    " is",
    " almost",
    " perfect",
    ""];

function chat() {
    for (var i = 0; i < chatMessages.length; i++) {
        var chatNow = chatMessages[i];
        if (chatNow != "") {
            alert(chatNow);
        }
    }
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/t5t93/4/)

Comment: so what your saying it instead of looking for name[i] just look directly at .length

Comment: I still use `chatMessages[i]`.

Comment: I'm just saying that instead of assigning `chatMessageCount` with a hard-coded number, use `chatMessages.length` to determine the length based on the actual number of elements in the array.

Comment: That way you don't have to update the variable when you add or remove things from the array.

Comment: im new to this, sorry, I threw this into JSfiddle and it wont run.

Comment: IT WORKS, thanks. is there a setting I need to set in fiddle i just use it the way I found it, I ahve no idea what those settings do.

Comment: If you're trying to call the function from an `onXXX` attribute, use one of the `No wrap` options. Otherwise, the function is defined inside another handler function, and it's not visible in the global scope.

Comment: ok, thanks, by the way, you are going to make me look so cool to my friends, thanks a bunch really